# Arduino can't process serial fast enough

Tags: c#, performance, arduino, serial-port, fastled

So my Arduino is taking almost 200ms processing a total of 128 bytes. The whole process without writing over the serial port is only taking  25ms.
Why is my Arduino bottlenecking so much?

**Arduino**

`setColor` is simply setting the color of the ledstrip using the FastLED library.

```c++
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() == 4){
    int led = Serial.read();
    int r = Serial.read();
    int g = Serial.read();
    int b = Serial.read();

    setColor(led, r, g, b);
    Serial.write(1);

    if(Serial.available() > 0) Serial.read();
  }
}
```

**C#**

In a loop I am doing the following to write the data:

```c#
attempt:
if (Port.isReady) {
  strip.Send(new byte[] { id, c.R, c.G, c.B });
  Port.isReady = false;
} else {
    goto attempt;
}
```

```c#
public void Send(byte[] bytes) {
  port.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

And I read the Arduino response using:

```c#
private const int DONE = 1;
public void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("- Serial port data received -");
    Console.WriteLine("Nr. of bytes: {0}", port.BytesToRead);
    if (port.ReadByte() == DONE) {
        isReady = true;
    }
    port.DiscardInBuffer();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "_without writing over the serial_" ? that's about all it does

Comment: I'm also doing a lot of calculations but those only take about 25ms. If I add that one line of writing to the Arduino then the whole process takes 250ms.

Comment: Without the whole program, we can't tell what baud rate you are using, nor how many LEDs you are controlling.  These (and perhaps other *unseen* things) affect the timing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it all depends on your baudrate. If your baudrate are 9600 you can receive 9600 bit per second, thats 1200 bytes.

So 128/1200 = 0.1066 = 107 ms spend on receiving 128 bytes.

Higher baudrates will give shorter readtime.

---

### Well why is it then taking 200ms you then ask?

My guess is that it is because of the many calls to `setColor()`
You are calling that once for every 4 bytes so that is 32 times.
I don't know the execution time on that function, but if it's something like 2-3ms you'r hitting that 200ms fast.